# i am getting error in this c program

Tags: c, string, ascii

i am trying to implement this c program , i want to expand strings
eg `a-z` to a b c d ...z etc 
when i put the input string as `a-z` i dont get the o/p but when i use the input string as `az` or without using the `-` i get the desired o/p

```
#include<stdio.h>
main()
{
    char s1[20] = "a   z", s2[10], s3[30];
    int k = 0, i = 0;
    while (s1[i] != '\0')
    {
        if((s1[i] >= 65 && s1[i]<= 90) || (s1[i] >= 97 && s1[i]<= 122))
            s2[k]=s1[i];
        i++;  k++;
    }
    s2[k] = '\0';
    for (int m = s2[0] ; m <= s2[1] ; m++)
       printf("%c ",m);
}
```

Comment: `s1` won't be filled with `a-z` when you use `char s1[20] = "a   z"`. And increment `k` from the body of the `if`,not outside it

Comment: thanks @CoolGuy , i got the answer , very silly mistake :)

Comment: Do `a-c-e` expand to `abcde` or `abc-e` ?

Comment: also `a-a` to `aa` or `a` or `a-a` ?

Comment: You should tick against an answer , if you find that it satisfies your problem. This helps in improving the quality of our  website.

Answer (score 0):

You should only update 'k' position when required:

```
if((s1[i] >= 65 && s1[i]<= 90) || (s1[i] >= 97 && s1[i]<= 122)) {
    s2[k]=s1[i];
    k++;
}

i++;
```

Furthermore your destination array `s2` (the one in which you store the expanded letters) shall be of at least 27 size (26+\0).

Answer (score 0):

Why bother so much? This small piece of code would do what you need:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char s1[4] = "a-z";
    int m;

    for(m=s1[0]; m<=s1[2]; m++)
    {
        printf("%c ",m);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: this is correct but the input is not always fixed ..it can be `-a-z` or `a-z0-6`, so i needed something generic

Comment: Okay, if the input is unpredictable, what you said is correct.

Answer (score 0):

as per your need:

```
char s1[20] = "a-z", s2[10],s3[30]; //a-z are now 3 characters


for(int m=s2[0]; m<=s2[2] ; m++) //loop for 3rd character i.e. "z".
   printf("%c ",m);
```

> output : a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>

char *expand(char *out, const char *in){
    size_t i, j;
    for(j = i = 0; in[i] != '\0'; ++i){
        if(in[i] != '-' || i == 0 || in[i+1] == '\0' || (unsigned char)in[i-1] >= (unsigned char)in[i+1]){
            out[j++] = in[i];
        } else {
            unsigned char ch_s = in[i-1] + 1, ch_e = in[i+1];
            while(ch_s < ch_e){
                out[j++] = ch_s++;
            }
        }
    }
    out[j] = '\0';
    return out;
}

int main(void){
    const char *test[] = {
        "a-z", "-a-e", "A-Z0-9", "a-a", "z-a", "a-e-g", "this is test-print"
    };
    char expanded[128];
    size_t i, size = sizeof(test)/sizeof(*test);
    for(i = 0; i < size; ++i){
        printf("%s expand to %s\n", test[i], expand(expanded, test[i]));
    }
    return 0;
}
#if 0
a-z expand to abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
-a-e expand to -abcde
A-Z0-9 expand to ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789
a-a expand to a-a
z-a expand to z-a
a-e-g expand to abcdefg
--/ expand to -./
test-print expand to test-print
#endif
```